# How to add vendor module without composer?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, swagger-php

I want to add a module Swagger(https://github.com/outeredge/SwaggerModule) to my Zend Framework 2 vendor library. It has instructions for using composer, but I want to do it without composer.

Can anyone help me on how to go about with this?
What I tried:

1. I downloaded the module and copied it to Vendor folder,
2. Added the `swagger.global.php` file to `config/autoload`
3. Added  `'SwaggerModule'`, to `application.config.php`

Comment: One has to wonder why you don't want to use composer... I imagine the problem is that `SwaggerModule` isn't being autoloaded. The solution to that depends on whether you have used composer for other modules.

Comment: I am using this on a system where I cannot use composer due to firewall setting

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2518)..  Using composer is way to go.

Comment: You can also just use Composer locally and upload the resulting files.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source files from [github](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) and add them to your models as a separate package.

You will have to do some refactoring to ensure proper *autoloading* and *avoid namespace conflicts* if any. Also the [executable files](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/tree/master/bin) will have to go to a build folder.

Adding the contents of https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/tree/master/src as a separate package (it's own folder/namespace) should do the trick.